# jquery timepicker not working in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova-2.0.0, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am creating an app in which i want to app datepicker to select birthdate so for that i tried to use **jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js** but the problem is when i tried to use it statically in the div then it shows the dateselector but when i try to create it dynamically it's not working can any one tell why its acting like this and where i am making mistake 
here is the code for creating dynamic datepicker:

```
    var creatText = $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type','text');
    creatText.attr('class','datetimepicker');
    creatText.attr('id','birthdate');
    creatText.attr('size','25');
    creatText.attr('placeholder','Birth Date');
    creatText.appendTo('#contentdemo');
```

here is the code for creating date selector statically and its working fine:

```
<div data-role="content" id="contentDemo">
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="c" style="margin-left: 8px;margin-right: 8px" id="dynamic_actionform">
</div>
  <input class='datetimepicker' placeholder="birth date" size='25'>
</div>
```

here is the example in github for the js files im using[enter link description here](https://github.com/vanetten/jquery-timepicker-addon-rails)
error in the logcat:

```
logcat09-05 06:37:41.943: D/CordovaLog(2822): Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance 09-05 06:37:41.943:

E/Web Console(2822): Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.7.1.js:552
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call .datetimepicker() on the new element after you've appended it to the DOM like so:

```
$('#contentdemo').append('<input type="text" id="birthdate" size="25" placeholder="Birth Date">');

// This should initialize the datepicker functionality
jQuery('#birthdate').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: i tried it but its showing error in the logcat..08-30 12:28:31.107: D/CordovaLog(6452): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
08-30 12:28:31.107: E/Web Console(6452): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-ui.js:8753

Comment: Ah ok. It looks like the problem lies with the version of jquery-ui you're using. Older versions still contain references to the deprecated jQuery.browser property. Try upgrading to jquery-ui 1.10+ to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I had update my jquery-ui to v1.10.3 know its showing this error in the  logcat09-05 06:37:41.943: D/CordovaLog(2822): Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance
09-05 06:37:41.943: E/Web Console(2822): Uncaught Error: no such method 'value' for slider widget instance at file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.7.1.js:552

Answer (score 0):

```
var creatText = $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type', 'text');
creatText.attr('class', 'datetimepicker');
creatText.attr('id', 'birthdate');
creatText.attr('size', '25');
creatText.attr('placeholder', 'Birth Date');
creatText.appendTo('#contentDemo');

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
```

You spelt `contentDemo` as `contentdemo` when appending.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EvZWh/3/)

Comment: i am not using jquery-ui.datepicker.js im using jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js which get date selector like android time selector in scroll view so that it becomes easier for user to select brthdate.

Comment: basically the same thing. If you are going to use 3rd party libraries either link to them or create a jsfiddle with them included. my question is updated with jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: if i am calling datetimepicker function then its giving an erro in the log for the filed which is creatd dynamically but hen i click on the filed which i had created statically its showing date selector.

Comment: look at my fiddle. The element which is having `datetimepicker()` called on it is dynamically added and is working.

Comment: Seems like it wont work in Chrome but it works in Firefox. Try hosting the javascript file elsewhere or just use it in your own code linking to your local version of the plugin.

Comment: i tried to run it on the firefox but still the same actually the problem with the dynamic field arise when the field is created inside a function bcz when tried to create field onload its showing the date selector but not when a function i called after the page is loaded and then the filed is created.

Comment: My fiddle example is working fine in Firefox and seemingly the only reason it is not working in Chrome is because jsfiddle cannot access the plugins javascript from the url i gave it.

Comment: did you check the error in the question bcz when i try to run the code and click on the date text it gives that error.