# how to return a value from function to another in js using phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am creating an app in which i am using jquery mobile autocomplete. To create the listview i am calling a function in js file. When a user enter the character in the input field it will call the js file and then i want to call another function which is return to access the data from data base and it will create and array object and this created array i want to pass back to the function called and then it will create an li base on that array.
Here is the code inside the **demoautocomplete.js**

```
function createlist(autocomplete_name){
var objdata=['user_name','user_id'];

$( "#"+autocomplete_name).on("listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var autocompleteData=new Array();
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
   getdatafromtable(autocompleteData,value); var dataarray=getdatafromtable(autocompleteData);
    if ( value && value.length > 1 )
    {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        for(var j=0;j<dataarray.length;j++)
        {

            html +="<li id='"+dataarray[j].id+"'>"+dataarray[j].user_name+"</li>";
        }
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            $.mobile.activePage.find('input[placeholder="Find a name..."]').attr('id','autocomplete');
        }
     $("ul>li").click(function()
             {
                var textval=$(this).text();
                var id=$(this).attr('id');
                $('#autocomplete').val(textval);
                $.mobile.activePage.find("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
                storeselectedid(id,autocompleteData);
        });
});
    }
function getdatafromtable(autocompleteData,value){
db.transaction(function(tx){
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    var selectQuery='select first_name||" "||last_name user_name,user_id from users where first_name like "%'+value+'%" or last_name like "%'+value+'%" limit 10';
    var selectQuery1='select account_name user_name,account_id from crm_account where account_name like "%'+value+'%" limit 10';
    tx.executeSql(selectQuery,[],function(tx,results){
        var dataset=results.rows;
        if(dataset.length>0){
        for(var i=0;i<dataset.length;i++)
        {
                    var item=dataset.item(i);
                    var element = new Object();
                        element['id']=autocomplete_name+"_"+i;

                    for(var j=0;j<objdata.length;j++)
                    {
                        element[objdata[j]]=item[objdata[j]];

                    }
                autocompleteData[i]=element; 
            }
return autocompleteData;
        }
    });
});  }
```

here the script code in html from where js will be called:

```
$(function(){
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a name..." 
data-filter-theme="d" >
</ul>
var autocomplete=$(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id',autocomplete_name);
    autocomplete.attr('data-role','listview');
    autocomplete.attr('data-inset',true);
    autocomplete.attr('data-filter',true);
    autocomplete.attr('data-filter-placeholder','Find a name');
    autocomplete.appendTo("#contentDemo");
    createlist(autocomplete_name); });
```

when `getdatafromtable`function is called it should create fill the data in the array object and pass that arrayobject back to the `createlist`function and then if loop should be executed.
here is the flow of code how it should work :
1. the page is loaded then when user enters a character in the input field.
2.it will go to thejs file then input value is assign to value variable. which i want to pass to the function getdatafromtable so base o that input it fetch the data from the database.
3.the retrive is stored in the array object than its pass back to the function from where it was called.
4.After retriving the array data it should create the li listview.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `getdatafromtable` function is properly made to return the array

```
var data_array = getdatafromtable(autocompleteData);
```

and in your `getdatafromtable` function you should have a return statement returning an array

Also dont name your variable the same as an already existing function. `autocompleteData` in this case is both a local variable and a function name.

Edit:

```
$("#" + autocomplete_name).on("listviewbeforefilter", function (e, data) {
    var autocompleteData = new Array();
    var $ul = $(this),
        $input = $(data.input),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html("");
    getdatafromtable(autocompleteData, $ul, $input, value, html);
});

function after_data_retrieved(autocompleteData, $ul, $input, value, html) {
    if (value && value.length > 1) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        for (var j = 0; j < dataarray.length; j++) {

            html += "<li id='" + dataarray[j].id + "'>" + dataarray[j].user_name + "</li>";
        }
        $ul.html(html);
        $ul.listview("refresh");
        $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
        $.mobile.activePage.find('input[placeholder="Find a name..."]').attr('id', 'autocomplete');
    }
    $("ul>li").click(function () {
        var textval = $(this).text();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#autocomplete').val(textval);
        $.mobile.activePage.find("[data-role=listview]").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
        storeselectedid(id, autocompleteData);
    });
}

function getdatafromtable(autocompleteData,  $ul, $input, value, html) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        var selectQuery = 'select first_name||" "||last_name user_name,user_id from users where first_name like "%' + value + '%" or last_name like "%' + value + '%" limit 10';
        var selectQuery1 = 'select account_name user_name,account_id from crm_account where account_name like "%' + value + '%" limit 10';
        tx.executeSql(selectQuery, [], function (tx, results) {
            var dataset = results.rows;
            if (dataset.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                    var item = dataset.item(i);
                    var element = new Object();
                    element['id'] = autocomplete_name + "_" + i;

                    for (var j = 0; j < objdata.length; j++) {
                        element[objdata[j]] = item[objdata[j]];

                    }
                    autocompleteData[i] = element;
                }
            }
            after_data_retrieved(autocompleteData, $ul, $input, value, html);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i have update the code as you said but nothing change still it not returning the value from getdatafromtable to createlist function..

Comment: I am getting an error in logcat 09-04 10:34:07.788: D/CordovaLog(5466): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
09-04 10:34:07.788: E/Web Console(5466): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/demoautocomplete.js:21

Comment: you put you return statement in the wrong area of the function. Move is so that it is called after everything else in the function

Comment: can you tell me were exactly should i put the return method and did you check the edited code do i calling the function properly and storing the return in variable correctly.

Comment: not sure why you added value as a parameter now you will have to call `getdatafromtable(somevar, someothervar)` and it doesnt seem to actually do anything

Comment: still its not returning the array from getdatafromtable function to the createlist its first executing the createlist function completely and then it starts the getdatafromtable function...

Comment: ahh i did not realise that `executeSql` was asynchronous. Your best bet is to change your code so that the remainder of your `listbeforefilter` callback is executed from the callback of `executeSql` ill update my answer with how

Comment: hey thanks for your help it worked great.I need to one more thing can you tell how to pass the selected list data to html file after user select a data from the list.sorry for troubling you again

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by that. `$("ul>li").click()` defines the handler to the click event on a list element if that is what you want. the function passed to that handler defines what happens when you click a list element. so if you wanted to update some elements HTML there you would call `$('#some_element').html('new html');`

Comment: what i mean is when the user will click on the listview $(ul>li).click() will get the id of the selected list and close the listview set the input filed with the selected list name then i want to pass the id to <script code > which is written in the main page from where the js is called for the autocomplete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36828/discussion-between-dgs-and-neerav-shah)

Comment: hi can you help me to solve this problem also http://stackoverflow.com/q/18531851/2307391

Comment: hii sorry to trouble you again can you help to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/18652236/2307391